# Early 2000s online PC game

Tags: identify-this-game, pc

I'm trying to remember an old PC game I used to play online, early 2000s.
I remember the game being a futuristic based game where you had a cyborg woman as the maim character. The character had a purple superhero like outfit on, white short hair and had a long visor covering her eyes. The aim of the game was to locate the port for save return home and the character would open her wings and fly off. This would end the game, but you'd get these round enemy troops that threw fire balls at you. The character's defence/kill techniques were swiping. I remember that if you accidentally swiped a generator, it would electrocute the character, but it would kill the enemy if they were close enough.
Sorry, don't have any more details. I believe the game title had the word 'sky' in it if I remember correctly.
Would really appreciate any thoughts ^_^

Comment: Was it first person, third person, top down etc ? In what way was it online - mutliplayer, co-op ?

Comment: Why are people voting to close? What's different about this to all the other game ID questions?

Comment: Nothing, that’s why they are voting to close.

Comment: @AlanB: an online game from the 2000s feels a lot less retro than an Apple II game from the 1970s. I'm generally in favor of game questions, but the line between modern and retro has to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: Given that this got enough close votes, I'd suggest asking /r/TipOfMyJoystick on Reddit and the #identify-a-game channel on the MobyGames Discord.